# Excel VBA Changing Data Source for Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

Okay, I have sifted through tons of posts and cannot get my code to run. I am trying to create a reconciliation report, which I have running just fine. The problem comes when I am trying to take each month's report and paste it into a master reconciliation file. I have everything working perfectly, except I cannot for the life of me figure out WHY my pivot table source won't change.

The error I am getting with the code as is:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Any suggestions? :-\

```
    Dim SrcData As String
    Dim PivTbl As PivotTable

    SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("$A$1:$H$" & LastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    On Error Resume Next
        Set PivTbl = Sheets("Report").PivotTables("ReportPivot")
    On Error GoTo 0
        If PivTbl Is Nothing Then
            'create pivot
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(PivTbl).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
            PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, _
            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

            PivTbl.RefreshTable
        End If
```

Comment: What is the line of the error?

Comment: Consider using only `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$" & lastrow)`. Make sure lastrow exists.

Comment: It is highlighting the whole section under the Else statement (minus the refresh code)

Comment: I tried that, same error. I have lastrow printing in debug each time I run, just to make sure it DOES exist! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the problem is here:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(PivTbl).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

I guess you cannot get a pivot table passing the table itself as argument: `.PivotTables(PivTbl)`

`PivTbl` is already the table you want.

```
PivTbl.ChangePivotCache.......
```